# Mixing natural width and Bootstrap width columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I've got a Bootstrap 3 form where I simply want to line up a bunch of spans in a neat row, degrading into a stack on mobile:

```
From [station1] to [station2] at [time]

From
[station1]
to
[station2]
at
[time]
```

Obviously I can do this, and it works:

```
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-1">From</div>
     <div class="col-md-3"><select>...</select></div>
     <div class="col-md-1">To</div>
     <div class="col-md-3"><select>...</select></div>
     ...
  </div>
```

However, it looks rather silly if the screen is wide:

```
    From       [station1]     to      [station2]     at     [time]
```

If I queue up some spans without the col-X-Y classes, they don't play nice with Bootstrap.  And if I try to mix together grid and non-grid spans or divs, they get ordered in weird and mysterious ways as shown in the last two rows of [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FX73/).  Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is not the solution to everything. You still have to write your own CSS at times. You can reduce your column widths for larger screens by using the appropriate classes, but that will not improve things much.

Instead, you are better off writing your own CSS. Style your elements to be `inline-block`, add some margin and padding. If you want to take it a step further you can write your own media queries to handle styles at reduced widths.

Look at line 260 in [the variables file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L261) in Bootstrap.

```
@screen-xs:                  480px;
@screen-xs-min:              @screen-xs;
@screen-phone:               @screen-xs-min;
```

You can use those variables to create viewport specific CSS.

```
@media (max-width: $screen-xs) {
  // Change spans to block
  span.my-field {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

If you are not using Sass or Less, you can hardcode the values of the variables. For example, `480px` instead of `$screen-xs`.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the columns in a smaller width col, such as `col-sm-5` or `col-sm-6`..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="col-lg-2">From</div>
     <div class="col-lg-2"><select><option>station</option></select></div>
     <div class="col-lg-2">To</div>
     <div class="col-lg-2"><select><option>station</option></select></div>
     <div class="col-lg-2">at</div>
     <div class="col-lg-2"><select><option>time</option></select></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/116599

Comment: That still looks off, in that the gaps are larger than they should. I don't think it's a good idea to use Bootstrap columns for this type of thing.

Comment: Looks tolerable though if you "text-right" align the text divs, so they're next to the selects.  (And why are you two downvoting each other?)

Comment: I don't know why I was downvoted. @Mohamad's solution is much harder as it requires a custom Bootstrap build. Why do that when this Bootstrap solution is out-of-the-box -- Bootstrap even has examples of nested columns in their docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: @jpatokal I'm not sure about the downvotes. @Skelly, my solution does not require a "custom build"--what is that, anyway? My solution requires a few lines of additional CSS. The idea that Bootstrap should do everything without any custom CSS is absurd. Also, classes such as `row` and `col` are not semantic and are only meant for quick prototyping. The docs recommend using the provided mixins. Heavens forbid anyone dares to write a custom line of CSS, because we want the web to look identical--like Bootstrap. You can (and should) still add your own CSS to a site after requiring Bootstrap.

Comment: using LESS variables (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) is customizing the Bootstrap baseline CSS .. or requires that you always include LESS in your files

Comment: @jpatokal have a look at this http://matthewcopeland.me/blog/2013/11/04/bootstrap-bankruptcy/

Comment: @Skelly 1. I'm not customising any variables. I am using them. 2. If you are not using Less or Sass, you can hard code the variables. Instead of `$screen-xs` he can use `480px` in the media query. I am showing the lines of the variables.less as reference, not so that he can tamper with it.

Comment: @Mohamad Of course, but your answer doesn't explain that ;-)

Comment: @Skelly, that's funny, because I took that part out before posting the answer. My text is from another answer I had given that has that info. Anyway, I'm glad you thought that was worth a down vote. :)

Comment: @Skelly I did. Note that technically I don't think there is anything wrong with your answer. I don't think using the grid is the right thing to do. That's just my opinion. If you have to though, and you are using Sass or Less, I would employ the `make-row` and `make-col-x` mixins.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach:

```
<span>From</span>
<br class="visible-xs visible-sm"/>
<span>...</span>
<br class="visible-xs visible-sm"/>
```

Looks nasty, but seems to work nice. I haven't found any issues yet.